# Does WeakReference have redundant properties?

Tags: .net, weak-references

WeakReference implementation in .NET has an IsAlive Property.

1) Are there any performance/behavior differences between using the `IsAlive` property or testing whether the `Target` property is not null?

2) `IsAlive` is a redundant property?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No.  Internally, IsAlive is doing almost exactly the same logic as checking target, and seeing if it's null.

2) Somewhat, since checking whether `ref.Target != null` is pretty much equivelent to `ref.IsAlive`.  However, `IsAlive` is more expressive, and potentially easier to understand when maintaining the code.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source code, there is no difference in behavior between them.  `obj.IsAlive` is simply more convenient and readable then `obj.Target != null`.

Comment: Note that while that may be the case in present implementations, it's possible that in future implementations of a possibly-hardware-assisted concurrent GC, retrieving the target of a `WeakReference` might substantially increase the likelihood of it surviving the next collection; if one isn't interested in the target, but merely wants to e.g. remove the `WeakReference` itself from a collection if its target has died, checking `IsAlive` would be better than checking the `Target`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not hard to imagine a concurrent garbage-collection system in which holding a reference to an object even momentarily would have a substantial likelihood of causing that object to survive the next GC (under .Net, it has a relatively small likelihood of doing so).  Under such a system, using an object's Target property to determine if it was dead could have the annoying side-effect of keeping the object alive longer than necessary.  Using the IsAlive property would avoid that risk.

Note that IsAlive can only be used reliably to determine if an object is dead.  If it reports that an object is alive, it may or may not be possible to acquire its target.